# map inside a panorama or pivot not an option. but then, how?

Tags: windows-phone, user-experience

I need to implement a page where I display items related to locations.

The user should be able to switch between viewing locations in a list and viewing the locations in the map control (as pointpoints).
A similar idea to this picture from iOS:
[image: screenshot]

I wanted this in a panorama but it won't work if the map is interactive.
So this forces me to have a search button somewhere which will open this page.

But it's not what I would like to do.

I want to show users nearby items easily, without the need for them to navigate to a separate page.

I tried to look for existing apps, the built-in app, Local Scout puts the map at the top above the panorama. But I cannot do this in my case.

What's the recommended way of implementing switching between a List and Map views similar to what I described above, in a panorama?

The only idea I have is that when user chooses the see issues on the map open a separate page with the map. Switching back, I need to navigate back to the panorama and make sure it is scrolled to the panorama item (something which as far as I seen is not easily done).

Answer (score 1):

If you are only going to have two items in your Panorama, I would actually suggest a Pivot page.  This would fall more in line with the design standards of Windows Phone.

You could place the map on the panorama but have a transparent button over it.  This would allow users to see what is actually on the map and when clicked, open to a new page that is now interactive.  This could be a nice way to implement it.

Something like this, perhaps?

```
 <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Map_Click" Height="560" BorderThickness="0">
                <Grid>
                    <maps:Map IsEnabled="False" LandmarksEnabled="True" Name="MapControlEvent"     ZoomLevel="15" Width="427" Height="877">

                    </maps:Map>
                </Grid>
```

Comment: I haven't yet thought about how to make the navigation, thanks for the tip. any ideas for my main problem? thanks

Comment: by the way, you touched an off-topic issue but somethign I also have in mind. I know that Pivot is more close to what's being recommended for what I need, but I have seen many apps using Panorama instead. Look to the built-in apps for example, Office or Local Scout

Comment: I think local scout would be considered a pivot page with a map at the very top.
I found a good blog post on the difference:
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/13/windows-phone-panorama-versus-pivot-ux-guidelines.aspx

I must have misunderstood your original question, though.  I thought you were looking for a suggestion with you navigation.

Comment: Local Scout uses a Panorama control, it's just that it doesn't have a title or background which shows the parallax effect. The Map is placed above it. My original question was how to implement switching between List and Map views, in a panorama.

Answer (score 0):

First up, I wouldn't use a Panorama or Pivot on this example, but switch visibility when pressing the button of the Map and the List. In other words, only have one page with both on them.

But if you do want to use something else... I would also suggest the Pivot control and take a look at the new [Windows Phone Toolkit for Windows Phone 8](http://phone.codeplex.com/)!
Example [here...](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80797#1336296)
Because you want to use the LockablePivot when the map is displayed, otherwise the user will not understand the difference between the swipe interaction on the map and the switching swipe to the other pivot item.